# Python scrapy spider not found KeyError

Tags: python, scrapy

For a couple of days now I have been trying to create a crawler in Scrapy and with every project I keep getting the same error: `spider not found`. No matter what changes I make or which tutorial I follow, it always returns the same error.

Can someone please suggest where I should be looking for the mistake?

Thank you!

Windows 10, python 2.7

```
C:.
│   scrapy.cfg
│
└───scrapscrapy
    │   items.py
    │   middlewares.py
    │   pipelines.py
    │   settings.py
    │   settings.pyc
    │   __init__.py
    │   __init__.pyc
    │
    └───spiders
            SSSpider.py
            SSSpider.pyc
```

**items.py**

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class ScrapscrapyItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    Heading = Field()
    Content = Field()
    Source_Website = Field()
    pass
```

**SSSpider.py**

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from Scrapscrapy.items import ScrapscrapyItem

class ScrapscrapySpider(Spider):
    name="ss"
    allowed_domains = ["yellowpages.md/rom/companies/info/2683-intelsmdv-srl"]
    start_url = ['http://yellowpages.md/rom/companies/info/2683-intelsmdv-srl/']

    def parse(self, response) : 
        sel = Selector (response)
        item = ScrapscrapyItem()
        item['Heading']=sel.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/article/div/div[1]/div[2]/h2').extract
        item['Content']=sel.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/article/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]').extract
        item['Source_Website']= 'yellowpages.md/rom/companies/info/2683-intelsmdv-srl'
        return item
```

**settings**

```
BOT_NAME = 'scrapscrapy'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['scrapscrapy.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'scrapscrapy.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'scrapscrapy (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
```

**commandline:**

```
C:\Users\nastea\Desktop\scrapscrapy>scrapy crawl ss
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\spiderloader.py:37: RuntimeWarning:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 31, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 63, in walk_modules
    mod = import_module(path)
  File "c:\python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named spiders
Could not load spiders from module 'scrapscrapy.spiders'. Check SPIDER_MODULES setting
  warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)
2017-02-19 14:21:16 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.2 started (bot: scrapscrapy)
2017-02-19 14:21:16 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scrapscrapy.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scrapscrapy.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'scrapscrapy'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('scrapy==1.3.2', 'console_scripts', 'scrapy')()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 142, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 88, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 149, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 57, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\crawler.py", line 162, in crawl
    crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\crawler.py", line 190, in create_crawler
    return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\crawler.py", line 194, in _create_crawler
    spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 51, in load
    raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
KeyError: 'Spider not found: ss'
```

**edit**

as eLRuLL suggested i added `_init_.py` files to the `spider` folder, also changed scrapy.spider to scrapy.spiders as it was telling me it's depricated. now the result cmd returns is this:

```
C:\Users\nastea\Desktop\scrapscrapy>scrapy crawl ss
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\spiderloader.py:37: RuntimeWarning:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 31, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "c:\python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\nastea\Desktop\scrapscrapy\scrapscrapy\spiders\SSSpider.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Scrapscrapy.items import ScrapscrapyItem
ImportError: No module named Scrapscrapy.items
Could not load spiders from module 'scrapscrapy.spiders'. Check SPIDER_MODULES setting
  warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)
2017-02-19 15:13:36 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.2 started (bot: scrapscrapy)
2017-02-19 15:13:36 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scrapscrapy.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scrapscrapy.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'scrapscrapy'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('scrapy==1.3.2', 'console_scripts', 'scrapy')()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 142, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 88, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 149, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 57, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\crawler.py", line 162, in crawl
    crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\crawler.py", line 190, in create_crawler
    return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\crawler.py", line 194, in _create_crawler
    spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 51, in load
    raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
KeyError: 'Spider not found: ss'
```

Answer (score 2):

looks like something happened with the `__init__.py` file in your `spiders` folder.

Try adding it yourself (leave it empty):

```
───spiders
        __init__.py
        SSSpider.py
        SSSpider.pyc
```

Comment: Thank you, will respond in the question section cause the error is too long to post here.

Comment: can you share the content of `scrapy.cfg`?

Comment: `# Automatically created by: scrapy startproject
#
# For more information about the [deploy] section see:
# https://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html

[settings]
default = scrapscrapy.settings

[deploy]
#url = http://localhost:6800/
project = scrapscrapy
`

Comment: maybe you changed some environment variables?

Comment: i just changed `from Scrapscrapy.items import ScrapscrapyItem` to 
`from .. import items` and it is finishing the process but it is not returning the results i was hoping for. anyway, i still have a lot to learn before i get what i am looking for i guess. Thank you for the help, I think i solved the error and now i will have to figure out what is it returning

Comment: i am trying to upvote you but i don't have the "status" for that yet :D

Comment: np, glad I helped, maybe it was because you had `from Scrapscrapy.items import ...` on uppercase, it should be `from scrapscrapy.items import ScrapscrapyItem`